What is going on? Rails installation error on Windows. yaml and database error. Should i migrate on Linux //Beginner
pkg_config: checking for pkg-config for yaml-0.1... -------------------- not found

PATH=.;C:/Ruby33-x64/lib;C:\Ruby33-x64\bin;C:\Ruby33-x64\msys64\ucrt64\bin;C:\Ruby33-x64\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Ruby33-x64\bin;c:/users/user/appdata/local/microsoft/windowsapps;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\users\user\appdata\local\microsoft\windowsapps; x86_64-w64-mingw32-pkg-config --exists yaml-0.1
package configuration for yaml-0.1 is not found
--------------------

find_header: checking for yaml.h... -------------------- no

PATH=.;C:/Ruby33-x64/lib;C:\Ruby33-x64\bin;C:\Ruby33-x64\msys64\ucrt64\bin;C:\Ruby33-x64\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Ruby33-x64\bin;c:/users/user/appdata/local/microsoft/windowsapps;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\users\user\appdata\local\microsoft\windowsapps; "gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby33-x64/include/ruby-3.3.0/x64-mingw-ucrt -IC:/Ruby33-x64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby33-x64/include/ruby-3.3.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DYAML_DECLARE_STATIC -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby33-x64/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,--no-as-needed     -lx64-ucrt-ruby330  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi -lbcrypt  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return !!argv[argc];
8: }
/* end */

PATH=.;C:/Ruby33-x64/lib;C:\Ruby33-x64\bin;C:\Ruby33-x64\msys64\ucrt64\bin;C:\Ruby33-x64\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Ruby33-x64\bin;c:/users/user/appdata/local/microsoft/windowsapps;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\users\user\appdata\local\microsoft\windowsapps; "gcc -IC:/Ruby33-x64/include/ruby-3.3.0/x64-mingw-ucrt -IC:/Ruby33-x64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby33-x64/include/ruby-3.3.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DYAML_DECLARE_STATIC -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong   -c conftest.c"
conftest.c:5:10: fatal error: yaml.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <yaml.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <yaml.h>
/* end */

--------------------



i was trying to install rails but this happened. I am stuck wondering what i have to do to get unstuck. It seems easy but i cannot find anything good on here.

In https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ make sure to install the bold one.


Please provide the core of your solution as text, not as non-inclusive picture of text. Because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors
